# Does ConnectyCube react native SDK supports Video/Audio Calling in react native app?

Tags: javascript, react-native, webrtc, connectycube

Does the available react native ConnectyCube SDK supports Video/Audio Calling (one-to-one and conference Calling) in react-native app?
As the documentation has javascript sdk details on video/audio calling.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ConnectyCube JS SDK supports video calling in React Native.
In order to build your project you need to use SDK “connectycube-reactnative”: “1.7.2” and ConnectyCube JS SDK 1.7.2.

Also ConnectyCube React Native Videochat samples have been released recently. Check it [here](https://github.com/ConnectyCube/connectycube-js-samples/tree/master/RNVideoChat).